# Javascript promises not waiting for resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I thought I had a decent understanding of promises, until I ran into a problem with a simplifed code snippet bellow.  I was under the impression that the console.log calls would output `first second third`, but instead results in `second third first`.

Can someone explain why the second and third promises are able to continue on without waiting for the first.

```
var Q = require('q');

(function() {

  var Obj = function() {

    function first() {
      var deferred = Q.defer();

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('in the first')
        deferred.resolve();
      }, 200);

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function second() {
      return Q.fcall(function() {
        console.log('in the second');
      })
    }

    function third() {
      return Q.fcall(function() {
        console.log('in the third');
      })
    }

    return {
      first:  first,
      second: second,
      third:  third
    }
  };

  var obj = Obj();
  obj.first()
    .then(obj.second())
    .then(obj.third());

}());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be invoking the function, but pass the function, like this

```
  obj.first()
    .then(obj.second)
    .then(obj.third);
```

**Output**

```
in the first
in the second
in the third
```

Comment: That did the trick.  The reason I was calling the functions is that in the actual code I need to pass in params to the promise methods, which were left out here.  It looks like I will have to wrap it in an additional function.  Thanks for the help